# Why JPA, Hibernate and jTDS always uses varchar(8000) for String columns?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jtds

I'm using JPA (Hibernate) and jTDS as my jdbc driver. Whenever the datatype of my entity columns are String, the created prepared statement uses `varchar(8000)` as its parameter. I've already tried to use `@Column(length=50)` in my mappings for example, but it seems to be ignored.

If I set `sendStringParametersAsUnicode` in jTDS connection, it uses `nvarchar(4000)` instead, but never respects the lentghs I define in my entities. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: what hibernate dialect is it using?

Comment: What is the issue exactly? What is the expected behavior? Are you talking about the length of columns in the generated table or is it something else?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Suppose I have the following class:

`@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String name;
    ...
}`

Whenever I need to insert a new student, the following statement is generated by hibernate/jpa/jTDS:

`@declare @p1 int, declare @p2 varchar(8000); insert into Student (id, name) values (@p1, @p2);`

My problem is that hibernate/jtds are not respecting the length = 50 in my @Column annotation. For varchar columns, the length is always 8000. Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question, but having recently run into this myself I thought I'd shed some light.

This seems to be intentional in the `jtds` driver.

If you look at **`TdsData.java`**, you will see this occur in this code-block:

```
} else {
    if (pi.isUnicode && len <= MS_LONGVAR_MAX / 2) {
        pi.tdsType = XSYBNVARCHAR;
        pi.sqlType = "nvarchar(4000)";
    } else if (!pi.isUnicode && len <= MS_LONGVAR_MAX) {
        CharsetInfo csi = connection.getCharsetInfo();
        try {
            if (len > 0 && csi.isWideChars() &&
            pi.getBytes(csi.getCharset()).length > MS_LONGVAR_MAX) {
                pi.tdsType = SYBTEXT;
                pi.sqlType = "text";
            } else {
                pi.tdsType = XSYBVARCHAR;
                pi.sqlType = "varchar(8000)";
            }
```